# How to click only on the colored part of the image but not on the white background

Tags: reactjs, react-native, image, react-native-image

I am trying to render an image in react native. I want to select any part of that image. By selecting I mean I am now rendering a circle every time I press on the image.

You can find the codes [here](https://github.com/prantaDutta/testing-image-area-select)

The image now looks like this.

[image: screenshot of the image]

If the image doesn't load, then a backup [image](https://ibb.co/qC8HXgk)

This is fine. It works exactly I expect it to. But I can also select in the white background which is something I want to avoid. I want to only enable the clicking when clicked inside the t-shirt colors not on the white background. Now, how can I prevent the users from clicking on the white background instead of the image?

I know why this is happening, I also tried to implement this using svg image (You can find it in the repo, check out the `SafeAreaRegion.tsx` file).

How can I implement this?

Comment: sorry, I am using react native, not expo

Comment: yes but you can also post RN codes there, unless you have some native dependency for the above error

Comment: Sorry, I am not really familiar with expo. But I created this link, https://snack.expo.dev/@prantadutta/selecting-image-area does this help?

Comment: yes workks, give me some time, will check

Comment: hey you cant @Pranta, for that image area you cant do anything unless its an svg .

Comment: @GauravRoy thanks for replying. My Github repo has an example with svg. You can check that out. I would have added that to the expo snack but I don't know how to implement svg with expo.